# Bruhat decomposition in GAP

Tags: finite-groups, gap

Certain finite groups (of Lie type) have a normal form for their elements through Bruhat decomposition. Does GAP or any of its packages have any tools to calculate this?

Comment: `??Bruhat` in GAP outputs `Help: no matching entry found`. Might be worth asking [GAP Forum](https://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the special linear group $\text{SL}(n,q)$, the symplectic group $\text{Sp}(n,q)$, the special unitary group $\text{SU}(n,q)$ and special orthogonal group $\text{SO}(n,q)$ in the natural representation for $n \geq 4$ and $q = p^f$ where $p$ is a prime number and $f$ an positive integer, the package "BruhatDecomposition" can be used (except for $p = 2$ in the orthogonal case).

In each case there is a function "BruhatDecompositionSX(stdgens, g)" (X in [L,p,U,O]) which returns an MSLP S and the Bruhat decomposition of g. If the MSLP S is evaluated with the stdgens, then the output is g in its Bruhat decomposition.
The stdgens can be obtained by the functions "LGOStandardGensSX(n,q)" and correspond to the Leedham-Green and O'Brien standard generators.

I hope this helps you at least in some cases.

Comment: Thanks that would help, but I can't find the package "BruhatDecomposition". It's not in the gap distributed packages; even a google search is not finding it.

Comment: I am also not aware of such package, and unable to find it.

Comment: Its available on Github on the page: https://github.com/danielrademacher/BruhatDecomposition2

Comment: Thanks for the link; surprised why google didn't find it. This is actually a very nice package. My initial interest is in the symplectic groups; the metric is compatible with gap's SP(n,q) groups. I don't think the decomposition works with arbitrary generators; for example using the (two) generators of SP(n,q) fails...that would have been a nice bonus if it worked, but I should be able to work with LGO generators. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. And yes, that would be great. Maybe there will be a function to express the LGO generators in terms of arbitrary generators and store that into an MSLP. Then one can easily combine the two MSLPs.

Comment: We maintain a list of GAP packages with their public repositories at https://gap-packages.github.io/ - I've suggested the author of BruhatDecomposition2 to add it there.