# Bruhat decomposition of parabolic subgroup from that of borel subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

For $G=Sp(n,q)$, I can take an arbitrary element $S$ and find its Bruhat decomposition according to the Borel subgroup (in this case lower triangular symplectic matrices). This is thanks to a previously asked and answered question [Bruhat decomposition in GAP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108573/bruhat-decomposition-in-gap/4113371#4113371). So I'm able to express $S=L_1 W L_2$. $L_i$ are lower triangular and $W$ is monomial (diagonal times permutation). Now I'd like to find a decomposition of $S$ using a different (larger,parabolic but not borel) subgroup of "block triangular" symplectic matrices : these are zero in the upper right quandrant so the have a form $[[A,0],[C,D]]$; so $S=T_1 V T_2$ where $T_i$ are block triangular. $V$ should end up being a monomial matrix is some canonical form. Is there a way to derive the second decomposition from the first?

Here's an example of how I use the [GAP package BruhatDecomposition](https://github.com/danielrademacher/BruhatDecomposition2) per the request in the comments (it's not redistributed with GAP so you'd have to install it yourself).

```
LoadPackage("BruhatDecomposition","0"); 
SetInfoLevel(InfoBruhat,0);

p:=2; n:=4; 
grp:=SymplecticGroup(2*n,p);

if(\mod(p,2)=0)then
 stdgens:=LGOStandardGensSpEvenChar(2*n,p);
else
 stdgens:=LGOStandardGensSp(2*n,p);
fi;

A:=Random(grp);
slp:=BruhatDecompositionSp(stdgens,A); 
slpx:=ResultOfStraightLineProgram(slp[1],stdgens);

L1:=slpx[1]^-1;
W:=slpx[3]*slpx[4];
L2:=slpx[2]^-1;

Print("check A=L1WL2 ",A=L1*W*L2,"\n");
Print("L1=\n");Display(L1);
Print("W=\n");Display(W);
Print("L2=\n");Display(L2);
```

Comment: I've just now seen the BruhatDecomposition package, but haven't tested it yet. If it outputs in Steinberg-Chevalley generators (the documentation seemed to suggest this, transvections for L and (signed) transpositions for W in SL), then I think you basically absorb some of the w into the L based on the ordering of the roots. In a simple case, it might look like $(x_1(s) x_2(t)) \cdot (w_1 w_2) \cdot (x_1(u) x_2(v)) = (x_1(s) x_2(t) w_1) \cdot w_2 \cdot (x_1(u) x_2(v))$

Comment: I've been running with the package for the last couple of weeks; it works well but I haven't been able to extend it to non-borel subgroups. I'd really like to see an approach based on roots or anything clever like that. In the meantime for q=2^n I can find a way to "normalize" the permutation by left and right multiplication with a block triangular matrix so that it ends up where A=diagonal(a) and a is a string of k 1's followed by (n-k) 0's. The other submatrices B,C,D are determined by A being a permutation and symplectic; so there are n+1 "canonical" forms and therefore n+1 double cosets.

Comment: At first glance it doesn't look trivial to program (like just regrouping parentheses), but I think you can factor the permutation yourself and move them into L1 and L2. I guess my only contribution here is saying "you don't need to use arbitrary blocks to normalize the perm, only perms" but probably you are already know that :P

Comment: BTW I think I figured out something you may be confused about: counting double coset requires keeping the parabolic subgroups fixed (so you don't get to change the size of the blocks between double cosets). I think you are counting maximal parabolics (and the borel) so that gives the number of positive roots (plus the borel), n+1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm only using the double cosets of a single group. Here's a reference with results that match what I'm getting <https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.14040.pdf>

Comment: Cool, I'm translating equation (5) into the notation I'm familiar with to see what they've done.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.09176.pdf (referenced in Tefjol's paper) has the standard Bruhat decomposition from group theory. For example w(C) in definition 17 varies over a set of size 2^n * n!    I'm still working on equation (5)

Comment: For equation (5), the products of $F_D$ and $F_U$ are in the parabolic subgroup of block triangular matrices. The middle element $F_\Omega$ is $W$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124502/discussion-between-jack-schmidt-and-unknown).

Comment: Have you considered contacting the author of the package?